# Styling Google Maps in swift 2

Tags: swift, google-maps

I'm facing a little problem I hope there is a simple solution.
Indeed I would like to custom my google map but I only found how to achieve this in Swift 3 (like the following instruction) but I'm currently developping in Swift 2.

```
do {
  // Set the map style by passing the URL of the local file.
  if let styleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "style", withExtension: "json") {
    mapView.mapStyle = try GMSMapStyle(contentsOfFileURL: styleURL)
  } else {
    NSLog("Unable to find style.json")
  }
} catch {
  NSLog("One or more of the map styles failed to load. \(error)")
}
```

Does somebody has an idea about how solve my problem in Swift 2 ?

Thank you for your answers !

Comment: what sort of styling do you need?

Comment: I just need a grey/silver style like the basic one you have in styling wizard tool of Google Maps.

Comment: You need to migrate your code from Swift 3 to Swift 2. They are not very different. Try to compile your code using Swift 2 compiler and fix the errors it outputs.

Comment: I wanted to do that but I can't find any equivalent to GMSMapStyle object in swift 2. I didn't faced any problem for camera but here it's strange.